# how to resolve the Bad Sql grammar error while using spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, batch-processing

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO match(id, city, date, player_of_match, venue, team1, team2, toss_winner, toss_decision,winner, result, result_margin, umpire1, umpire2)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match(id, city, date, player_of_match, venue, team1, team2, toss_winner, toss_de' at line 1
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:1034) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:373) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:182) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
at com.dev.IPLDashboard.IplDashboardApplication.main(IplDashboardApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match(id, city, date, player_of_match, venue, team1, team2, toss_winner, toss_de' at line 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:192) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:224) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:853) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:435) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:794) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$4(JdbcTemplate.java:1048) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match(id, city, date, player_of_match, venue, team1, team2, toss_winner, toss_de' at line 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:832) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:8.0.25]
... 62 common frames omitted

2021-05-31 23:10:34.943  INFO 4888 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step1] executed in 528ms
2021-05-31 23:10:34.966  INFO 4888 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=28}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 570ms
2021-05-31 23:10:34.967  INFO 4888 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
2021-05-31 23:10:34.967  INFO 4888 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67782677/edit) your question. Providing only a stack trace is not a good question. However, from the looks of your error, you have some malformatted SQL.

Comment: [`match`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) is the name of a function in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is with table name because match is a keyword in mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-M). Please either use different name or use match within backticks `match`. This should fix your problem.